# First publication of Pierre Deligne

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

The first publication of [Pierre Deligne](http://www.ias.edu/people/faculty-and-emeriti/deligne) was *Congruences sur le nombre de sous-groupes d’ordre $p^k$ dans un groupe fini*, Bull. Soc. Math. Belg. XVIII 2 (1966) pp. 129–132. I do not have access to this publication. What exactly did he prove here? Translated from the French the title means *Congruences concerning the number of subgroups of order $p^k$ in a finite group*.

Comment: You might want to consider accepting answers, which can be done by clicking the tick on the top left of answers. This gives the answerer an extra +15 rep. and shows that question is the one that served you most. Also, it shows the question is "answered", which helps users filter through open questions more easily.

Comment: Done of course!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I will paraphrase from MathSciNet review number MR0202821 (34 #2680), written by B. Chang:

Let $G$ be a group of order $p^sh$, with $(p,h)=1$ and let $d_k$ be the number of subgroups of $G$ of order $p^{s−k},\,\, 0\leq k\leq s.$ The main results are that:

 1. $d_k=1 \mod p$

 2. If a Sylow p-subgroup S is elementary abelian or cyclic, then $d_k$ is congruent mod $p^{k+1}$ to the number of subgroups of S of order $p^{s−k}$.

 3. If S is not cyclic then $d_1=1+p \mod p^2$.

**Note** (July 26th 2018, NH) one can find the publication [here](http://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/Congruence%20sur%20le%20nombre%20de%20sous-groupes%20d%27ordre%20pk%20dans%20un%20groupe%20fini.pdf)!

Comment: Jim, thanks very much!!!