# Wielandt's proof of Sylow's theorem.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

Let $|G|=p^{n}m$, and let $0\leq k\leq n$. Then the number of subgroups of $G$ of order $p^k$ is congruent to $1$ modulo $p$.

I know Wielandt's proof in the case $k=n$, which is standard, but I dont know how to use that proof to prove this above modification. Clearly the set $S$ on which we should make $G$ act by left multiplication has to be the set of all subsets of size $p^k$ and then we know that $\displaystyle \binom{p^{k}r} {p^{k}}$ is congruent to $r \bmod p$. But somehow using the Orbit-Stabilizer theorem I am unable to prove the above modification.

Could someone help me prove the above statement using a modification of Wielandt's proof?

Comment: You might want to check also this [entry][1] 


  [1]: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203850/why-is-the-number-of-subgroups-of-a-finite-group-g-of-order-a-fixed-p-power-cong/203894#203894

Comment: I would say, this is Frobenius theorem (1895), rather than Sylow (1872). The reason is, this theorem appears in a paper of Frobenius, whose title is *generalization of Sylow theorems* and one of the generalization is the theorem you stated. It is not so easy to derive generalization from Sylow's original (third) theorem. see also my answer for similar question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1586060/the-number-of-p-subgroups-of-a-group/1593829#1593829

Answer (score 25, accepted):

None of the versions of Wielandt's proofs of Sylow's Theorem that I have seen assume that $k=n$. I will cut and paste the proof from some lecture notes I have.

*Theorem.* Let $G$ be a finite group and let $p^\beta$ divide
$|G|$, where $p$ is prime. Let $k$ be the number of subgroups of $G$ of order
$p^\beta $.  Then $k \equiv 1 \pmod{p} $.

*Proof.*
Let $|G| = p^\alpha t$ with $p\nmid t$, so $\beta \le \alpha$.

Let $\Omega $ be the set of all subsets of $G$ of order $p^\beta $.
So
$|\Omega | =
\left( \begin{array}{c} p^\alpha t \\ p^\beta \end{array} \right)$.

Let $G$ act on $\Omega $ by right multiplication; i.e. if
$S \in \Omega$, then $S^g = Sg = \{sg \mid s \in S\}$.

Let $\Gamma$ be an orbit of $G^\Omega$.
If $T \in \Gamma$ and $x\in T$ then $1\in Tx^{-1} \in \Gamma$ so there is a set
$S\in \Gamma$ with $1\in S$.

Consider the stabilizer, ${\rm Stab} _G(S)$.
If $g\in {\rm Stab} _G(S)$ then $Sg=S$ so $1g = g \in S$.
Thus ${\rm Stab} _G(S) \subseteq S$.

1. Suppose that ${\rm Stab} _G(S) = S$, so $S$ is a subgroup of $G$.
   Then, by the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem,
   $|\Gamma| = |G|/|{\rm Stab} _G(S)| = p^{\alpha }t/p^{\beta } =
   p^{\alpha -\beta }t $ and
   $\Gamma$ is the set of right cosets of $S$ in $G$. Thus only one element
   of $\Gamma $ is a subgroup.
   Conversely, if $T$ is a subgroup of $G$ of order $p^{\beta}$ then
   $T^G$ (the orbit of $G^\Omega$ containing $T$) is the set of
   right cosets of $T$ in $G$ so has length $p^{\alpha -\beta }t $
2. Suppose that ${\rm Stab} _G(S) \ne S$.
   Then $|S| > |{\rm Stab} _G(S)|$, so  $|\Gamma | > p^{\alpha -\beta }t $.
   Since $|\Gamma |$ divides $|G| = p^{\alpha }t $ we have
   $p^{\alpha -\beta +1}$ divides $|\Gamma |$.
   So by 1) no element of $\Gamma$ is a subgroup of $G$ in this case.

Hence, there are exactly $k$ orbits whose stabilizer has size $p^\beta $
and these orbits have have length $p^{\alpha -\beta }t $, whereas
those orbits whose stabilizer has size less than $p^\beta $ have length
divisible by  $p^{\alpha -\beta +1} $.

So
$|\Omega | = kp^{\alpha -\beta }t + l p^{\alpha -\beta +1}  $ for some $l$,
and hence $$|\Omega |/p^{\alpha -\beta } = kt + lp \equiv kt \pmod{p}.$$
Since $p \nmid t$, there is a unique $u \in \{1,\ldots,p-1\}$ with
$ut \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$, and multiplying by $u$ gives
$$k \equiv |\Omega |u/p^{\alpha -\beta } \!\!\!\pmod{p} \equiv
 \left( \begin{array}{c} p^\alpha t \\ p^\beta \end{array} \right)u
/p^{\alpha -\beta }\!\!\! \pmod{p}.$$

It is possible to prove directly that this last expression equals
1 mod $p$, but we can avoid that as follows.
Note that $k \pmod{p}$ is a function of $|G|$ and $p^\beta$ only,
and so it is the same for all groups of order $p^{\alpha} t$. So $k
\pmod{p}$ can be
determined from $G=C_{p^{\alpha} t}$, the cyclic group of order $p^{\alpha} t$.

Hence  $k \equiv 1  \pmod{p}$, since a cyclic group $G$ has a unique
subgroup of each order dividing $|G|$.

$\mathbf{Additional\ Remark\!:}$ This last trick of using the fact that the number of subgroups modulo $p$ depends only on $|G|$ is due to Graham Higman. In his original proof, Wielandt proved directly that the expression in the final displayed formula is congruent to $1$ modulo $p$.

Comment: Wait, if I understood correctly, your $k$ is the number of orbits that contains a subgroup (of order $p^\beta$), but should that not depend on the group structure? I mean, the way that the stabilizer behaves should depend on $G$?

Comment: For instant, this can be applied to $\beta=k$, in which case the groups are Sylow $p$-subgroups, but abelian groups always have a unique Sylow $p$-subgroups, whereas non-abelian groups not necessarily.

Comment: Yes of course $k$ depends on $G$. It is the value of $k$ modulo $p$ that depends only on $|G|$ and not on the structure of $G$.

Comment: Very nice solution, especially last argument using cyclic groups!

Comment: @DerekHolt That last trick with the cyclic group, is that yours or someone else's? I've always seen the n-choose-r evaluated modulo $p$.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven I am afraid I cannot claim credit for it - it is due to Graham Higman. I should have mentioned that in the proof, so I will edit it.