# Number of the subgroups of a $p$-group with order $p^k$ is congurent to $1$ modulo $p$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

Let $G$ be a $p$ group of order $p^n$ and $k\leq n$.

> **Theorem**:Number of the subgroups of $G$ with order $p^k$ is congurent to $1$ modulo $p$.

I have found a proof of this theorem in Rotman's book but I wonder that "Is there any shorter or elegant proof for this theorem" ?

Comment: There is a proof by Wielandt, which applies to any finite group of order divisible by $p^k$. You can find it in my answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/479839

Comment: @DerekHolt: I am not asking the proof of Sylow's theorem. $G$ is already a $p$ group. Do you mean that when we take $m=1$ then $|G|=p^n$ then the therem can be applied to this problem ?

Comment: Yes that's right, it's a more general result than the one you are asking about. The proof may not be shorter than the one in Rotman's book, but it could be said to be elegant.

Comment: @DerekHolt: I liked this proof. It also shows existence of sylow-p subgroup. Can this method be used for proving Schur Zasenaus therem ? $N$ is normal subgroup of $G$ such that $(|N|,|G:N|)=1$. Let $\Omega$ be set of all subset of $G$ with cardinality $|G:N|$ and $G$ acts on $\Omega$ by right multiplication. ..