# A weaker version of Sylow's theorems

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Prove that the number of normal subgroups of order $p^s$ of a finite $p$-group $G$ is congruent to $1$ mod $p$.

I know this result is a weaker version of Sylow's theorems. But without using Sylow's theorems, how can we prove it?

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how this is a weaker version of Sylow?

Comment: You could let $G$ act on the set of all subgroups of order $p^s$ (by conjugation), and count the number of fixed points (note that a fixed point is precisely a normal subgroup)

Comment: Are you sure that it concerns *normal* subgroups? Theorem 4.8 in Rotmans 'An Introduction to the Theory of Groups' states it for subgroups (not necessarily normal).

Comment: @drhab : proving it for normal subgroups would prove it for the set of all subgroups (by the usual fixed point lemma - see my previous comment)

Comment: I know theorem 4.8 in Rotman 'An Introduction to the Theory of Groups', it proves the result for the subgroups of $G$. But how can we prove the case normal subgroups?

Comment: Much more is true: please read my entry http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203850/why-is-the-number-of-subgroups-of-a-finite-group-g-of-order-a-fixed-p-power-cong/203894#203894. It contains the answer to your question.

Comment: @Nicky Hekster: Thank you so much

Comment: @User111636 - you are very welcome, I hope you appreciate the beauty of all those theorems!

Comment: @Nicky Hekster: Your Remark of your comment on that link looks like the answer of Pralad Vaidyanathan.

Comment: Yes, and his $S_0 \subseteq S$ is the set of *normal* $p$-subgroups on which $G$ acts trivially by conjugation, So the elements of $S_0$ have an orbit of length $1$, the rest of the elements of $S$ (the non-normals) have an orbit length $\geq p$, so they mod out to $0$. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Since you know this fact for all subgroups, the normal case is simple. The following lemma is what you need (the proof is almost identical to the proof, using the class equation, that $Z(G) \neq \{e\}$ when $G$ is $p-$ group)

> Let $G$ be a $p-$group acting on a set $S$, and let
>   $$
> S_0 = \{x \in S : g\cdot x = x \quad\forall g \in G\}
> $$
>   Then, $|S| \equiv |S_0|\pmod{p}$

Now, let $S$ be the set of all subgroups of $G$ of order $p^k$, and let $G$ act on $S$ by conjugation. Check that $S_0$ is precisely the set of all normal subgroups of order $p^k$.

Comment: I see your idea. But can you explain more precise why $S_0$ is the set of all normal subgroups of order $p^k$?