# Let a finite group $G$ have $n (>0)$ elements of order $p$ (a prime). If the Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ is normal, then does $p$ divide $n+1$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

Suppose $G$ is a finite group and $p$ is a prime that divides $|G|$. Let $n$ denote the number of elements of $G$ that have order $p$. If the Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ is normal, then is it true that $p$ divides $n+1$? I know that $p-1=\phi(p)\mid n$ but I cannot approach further. Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to point out that this makes sense. For example:  $\mathbb Z_9 = \{ \bar 0, \bar 1, \bar 2, \bar 3, \bar 4, \bar 5, \bar 6, \bar 7, \bar 8 \}$ is a p-group with $n=2$ elements of order $3$.

Comment: We have $n=t(p-1)$ where $t$ is the number of subgroups of order $p$. But $t \equiv 1 \pmod p$ by Sylow's Theorem, so $p$ divides $n+1$.

Comment: @DerekHolt : I think Sylow's theorem say that no. of Sylow p-subgroups is of the form $pk+1$ ( which is $1$ here ) . Does it also say that no. of subgroups of order $p$ is of the form $ps+1$ ?

Comment: Yes, Wielandt's proof gives that. See my answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/479839/wielandts-proof-of-sylows-theorem According to that post, this result is due to Frobenius rather than to Sylow.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, a more general result holds:

> Let $G$ be a finite group, and $p$ a prime divisor of $|G|$. Then, there are $1\pmod p$ subgroups of order $p^k$, for every $k\in\{0,1,\dots,k_{max}\}$.

This result is due to Frobenius, and later variously contributed by Wielandt, Krull, Gallagher, Higman (just to mention the ones occurring in the proofs cited right after). In this site, you can find proofs of this theorem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/479869/1092170), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1593829/1092170), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4495075/1092170).

Since this holds irrespective of the Sylow $p$-subgroup being unique (normal), I suspect that such extra assumption is meant to bring some simplification in the particular case of $p$-groups (as parent group). In fact, if the Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, say $P$, is unique (hence normal), then any $p$-subgroup of $G$ is contained in $P$$^\dagger$, and we can search for proofs of the theorem above in the particular case of $G$ a $p$-group: [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1586494/1092170) provides a solution in such a setting.

So, in a way or another, we have (in particular!) that the number of subgroups of order $p$ in your $G$ is $1\pmod p$. But the number of subgroups of order $p$, say $N_p$, and the number of elements of order $p$, *i.e.* your $n$, are connected by the formula$^{\dagger\dagger}$:
$$n=N_p(p-1)$$
and hence from $N_p\equiv 1\pmod p$ follows $n\equiv -1\pmod p$, namely $p\mid (n+1)$.

---

$^\dagger$Let $H$ be a $p$-subgroup of $G$ of order $p^k$, *not* contained in $P$. Then $|H\cap P|\le p^{k-1}$, and hence $K:=PH$ is a subgroup of $G$ of order $|K|\ge (p^{k_{max}}p^k)/{p^{k-1}}=$ $p^{k_{max}+1}$, contradicting the maximality of $P$.

$^{\dagger\dagger}$In fact, every element of order $p$ lies in one and only one subgroup of order $p$, and any of these latter has $p-1$ elements of order $p$.

Answer (score 0):

Every element of order $p$ is contained in the Sylow $p$ subgroup (this is a slight extension of Sylow II), so you want to know that the number of elements of order $p$ in a $p$-group, plus one, is divisible by $p.$ This is true for a cyclic group of order $p.$ Now, note that a $p$ group has non-trivial center, so has a central element of order $p,$ which should be enough for the induction step.

**EDIT** Here is a complete argument, along slightly different lines. As above, we only need to consider $p$-groups. Now, consider the set $X$ of elements of order $p$ in a $p$-group $G,$ and the conjugation action of $G$ on that set. We have a variant of the class equation:
$$
|X| = n_Z + \sum |G|/C(x),$$ where the sum is over conjugacy classes of non-central elements, and $n_Z$ is the number of central elements of order $p.$ Every summand is divisible by $p,$ so we need to only consider $n_Z.$ Now, since the center is an abelian group, we need to show the result for abelian groups. By the fundamental theorem of abelian groups, we know that an abelian group is a product of cyclic groups. For cyclic group, the result is clear. Now, suppose $G = H_1 \times H_2,$ then, it is easy to see that $n(G) = n(H_1) + n(H_2) + n(H_1) n(H_2).$ Indeed, the elements of order $p$ in $G$ are those of the form $(1, x),$ where $x$ is of order $p$ in $H_2,$ and those of the form $(y, 1),$ with $y$ of order $p$ in $H_1,$ and those of the form $(x, y)$ (as above. Now use induction on the number of direct summands in $G.$

Comment: If $f(p,G)$ denotes the no. of elements of $G$ of order $p$ , then is $f(p,G)=f(p,Z(G))+f(p,G/Z(G))$  ?

Comment: @Saun Dev, no not true, take $G=Q$, the quaternion group of order $8$, and take $p=2$.

Comment: @SaunDev See edit.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Exercise 24.59 in Gallian's *Contemporary Abstract Algebra* 8/e.

By Sylow 2nd Theorem,
there exists only one Sylow $p$-subgroup $L$.
For any subgroup $H$ of order $p$,
by Sylow 1st Theorem,
$H\leq L$.
By Exercise 24.41,
there exists a subgroup $N$ of order $p$,
which is normal in $G$.
By these two things,
we can conclude that $N\lhd L$.

If $N\not\subseteq H\leq L$ and $|H|=p$,
verify that $H/N=\{hN\mid h\in H\}$ is a subgroup of $L/N$.
By Correspondence Theorem,
there exists $K$ such that $N\leq K$ and $K/N=H/N$.
Note that $|K/N|=|H/N|=p$ and $|K|=p^2$.
By the Corollary of Theorem 24.2,
$K$ is abelian.
Write $K/N=\langle kN\rangle$,
where $k\notin N$.

Since
$$\langle kn_i\rangle/N
\ni(kn_i)^mN
\stackrel{K\text{ is abelian}}{=}k^m n_i^mN
=k^m N
=(kN)^m
\in \langle kN\rangle
=K/N,
$$
we have $\langle kn_i\rangle/N=K/N$ for each $n_i\in N=\{n_1, n_2, ...,n_p\}$.
Note that $|\langle kn_i\rangle/N|=|K/N|=p$.
So $\langle kn_i\rangle$ is a subgroup of order $p$.
Hence,
$\langle kn_1\rangle, \langle kn_2\rangle, ..., \langle kn_p\rangle$
are all distinct subgroups of $L$ whose order is $p$
such that $\langle kn_i\rangle/N=K/N$.
The $p$ subgroups $\langle kn_1\rangle, \langle kn_2\rangle, ..., \langle kn_p\rangle$ of $L$ correspond to a same subgroup $K$.

Similarly,
except $N$,
every $p$ subgroups of order $p$ in $L$ correspond to a same subgroup of order $p^2$.
Let $s$ be the number of subgroups of order $p$ in $L$.
Then $p\mid (s-1)$.
Note that
$s=\frac{n}{p-1}$,
as the following figure indicates.

[image]

Therefore,
\begin{eqnarray*}
p\mid (s-1)=\left(\frac{n}{p-1}-1\right)
&\Rightarrow& p(p-1)\mid n-(p-1)\\
&\Rightarrow& p\mid n-p+1\\
&\Rightarrow& p\mid n+1
\end{eqnarray*}